# Span columns causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, tablelayout

I simply want to modify the span layout attribute of a textview (called t) in order to let it span 2 columns inside a table. I use the code

```
TextView t = new TextView(WineActivity.this);
t.setTextSize(15);
TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) t.getLayoutParams();
params.span = 2; 
t.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Quite misteriously to me, the second line of the code generates a NullPointerException. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Please show your XML.

Comment: the textview is not declared in XML, but one line before with     TextView t = new TextView(WineActivity.this);

Comment: Add a breakpoint on this line of code, check to see the value of `t` as it runs through the span change. It may not be created by the time it runs the code; therefore, hitting returning Null.

Comment: I think it is created at that time, otherwise I couldn't set its size I guess.

Answer (score 0):

"params" is null.

I'm guessing that t.getLayoutParams is probably null as well, but seeing more code would help us.

Comment: I added two lines, but any other part seems not that relevant to me. Immediately after I set the text of the textview and add it to a row of a table. All of this in the PostExecute part of an AsyncTask...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're calling (TableRow.LayoutParams) t.getLayoutParams(); but t doesn't generate LayoutParams until the program is already running and showing the page.

The simplest solution is just to create new params yourself.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
params.span = 3;
row.setLayoutParams(params);
```